# Can't connect to Unix Socket with C#

Tags: c#, sockets, unix, .net-5

I'm trying to attach to a Unix socket that is exposed from a Docker container as a mounted volume. Running the above immediately gives an error:
`Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`

This error happens regardless of whether or not the socket is listening, so it leads me to believe something is going on with Windows 10, and trying to connect to a Unix domain socket with .net5.0. It's almost like it fails trying to allocate a listener, and never even tries to connect. Has anyone else dealt with this, am I missing something??

This seems like a simple enough task, so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

```cs
   var socketName = "C:\\Users\\user1\\ipc\\node.socket";
   var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified);
   socket.Bind(new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(socketName)); << exception here

Exception:
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Comment: The protocoltype has to be ProtocolType.Tcp

Comment: Changing the protocol gives the error: 'The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists.'

Comment: The address family is also wrong : ipAddress.AddressFamily

Comment: I'm connecting to a Unix socket file, not an IP address

Comment: You cannot connect between a unix socket and a windows machine.  Unix socket is internal to a unix machine.  See : https://serverfault.com/questions/124517/what-is-the-difference-between-unix-sockets-and-tcp-ip-sockets

Comment: I ended up getting it to work with socat and mapping it to a TCP connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was able to get this to work by using socat and mapping the unix socket file to a TCP connection. This was fairly simple using another container.

```yaml
##docker-compose.yml
    some-service:
      ...
      volumes: ##map the socket in to a volume
          - socket-vol:/opt/socket/ipc
    socat: ##remap the unix socket to TCP so we can develop against is easily
        image: alpine/socat
        ports:
            - 127:0.0.1:1234:1234
        command: tcp-listen:1234,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/opt/socket/ipc/node.socket
        volumes:
            - socket-vol:/opt/socket/ipc

volumes:
    socket-vol:
```

Then I had to change my C# code to use the new socket type:

```cs
var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
client.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1",1234, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
```

And then I was able to access the socket. @jdweng makes a good point in the original comments that you cannot attach to Unix sockets from a windows machine due to file permissions. Thus, mapping in to a TCP socket lets us sidestep that issue. I will need to alter my code when it is time to create an executable, but this allows me to develop and debug natively in Windows.